# n is a valid starting character in a JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I was reading through this [Node JS sample code](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_consumers) and I found it curious that they represented the error message for trying to parse `"not json"` as the following error: `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

But yeah, `JSON.parse("no")` complains about the 2nd character, not `n` itself.

Why is that so? What valid JSON can there be starting with `n`?

Comment: Oh that's funny. :-) [Quentin's right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50022165/157247) (as usual). Subtle!

Comment: This is interesting and revealing in that Node tells me, *SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1*. So, position 1? And "o" is a token? Then what's "n"? Firefox gives a less weird error message, *unexpected keyword at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data*, indicating that it parsed (in a lexer layer?) the whole word as a keyword, but since it isn't `null`, `true`, or `false` the keyword as a whole is bad.

Comment: @Pointy - yes I think Firefox is more accurate in the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`null` is valid JSON.

See [json.org](http://json.org/) or [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-3) for a list of valid JSON values.

Answer (score 0):

A valid [JSON](http://json.org/) can start with `{`, `[` and `"` for values, like numbers, strings with quotes around, boolean values, like `true` or `false` and `null`, but not `undefined`.

```js
console.log(typeof JSON.parse("true"));
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because JavaScript objects as Strings are returned as [object object]. Hence it refers to 'o' from 'object' as unexpected token. Try this in console

```
var object = {name: "Me"}

console.log(object.toString())

JSON.parse(object)
```

Comment: The value being parsed is the string `"no"` not `{some: object}`.

Comment: If that's true than the error should be the same for `JSON.parse("na")`, yet this time around will complain about token `a` at position 1

Comment: @Adelin — Yes. It is true. The error should be the same for that. When I test it, the error **is** the same for that.

Comment: Yes, I did get now about valid JSON values from @Quentin